# Getting and setting the value from input use javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a input from website which defines like this:

```
<input type="text" name="postdb[title]" size="60" value id="title" class="input_text">
```

I've tried this:

```
document.getElementsByName('postdb[title]')[0].value='test'
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById('title').value='test'
```

but it doesn't work,how to set the value of this input use javascript?

edit:

I found that this input is insideof `<form name="FORM..`,so how to find it in that form use javascript?

edit:solved;
its actually inside of FORM from iframe,so I just use this:

```
var vform =document.frames['main'].document.forms['FORM'];
vform.elements['title'].value='test'; thanks for help,
```

Comment: `getElementById()` works fine for me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wLxm/). Maybe you have another element with the same `id` somewhere?

Comment: [Both should work](http://jsfiddle.net/CdUNA/). Is the DOM ready when your code runs?

Comment: I got the feeling the DOM isn't ready.

Comment: The markup is invalid. _Line 1, Column 57: "VALUE" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute_

Comment: I found the reason,the input is inside of a form called FORM, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DOM was probably not loaded yet.

```
<!-- this will fail -->
<script type="text/javascript">var el = document.getElementById('element');</script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

The above example will fail because we are trying to search an element that has not yet loaded. A mistake easily made!

```
<!-- this will not -->
<div id="element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">var el = document.getElementById('element');</script>
```

By running the javascript after the required DOM has loaded, we are able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<input type="text" name="postdb[title]" size="60" value="" id="title" class="input_text">

document.getElementById('title').value='test';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('title').value = 'test';
});
```

Demo Here: **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLLAQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

Both should work for you but,make sure when you are calling `document.getElementById();` or `document.getElementsByName();` does the `<input>` element exist in your page?